# Hibernate Envers : StackOverflow error when auditing objects

Tags: hibernate, stack-overflow, hashcode, hibernate-envers

I have a problem with Envers and auditing entities. I have an existing application which, unfortunately, isn't really well built, and I'd like to apply envers on it.
Hibernate was already working properly.

Envers is configured correctly (or at least I believe so) with these properties in the hibernate.cfg.xml :

```
<property name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy">org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy</property>

<listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="post-insert" />
<listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="post-update" />
<listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="post-delete" />
<listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="pre-collection-update" />
<listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="pre-collection-remove" />
<listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="post-collection-recreate" />
```

The auditing tables are created and populated with a copy of the tables, and a foreign key to an existing revision.

None of the audit works, and here is an example :
I want to create an object "FAQ". It has two String field, and a many-to-one relation with the object "User"."User" has 12 one-to-many relationships, 1 many-to-one and 3 many-to-many.
In order to save the "FAQ" object, I have to set its "USER" field, with the one retrieve from the database : 
faq.setUser(userDao.getUser(id));
I think the following error comes from the relation between the object, but I can't really figure out why.

The error occur when I try to save the faq object :

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
     at java.util.HashMap.entrySet(HashMap.java:480)
     at java.util.AbstractMap.hashCode(AbstractMap.java:434)
     at java.util.MapEntry.hashCode(MapEntry.java:75)
     at ....
```

And so on. The only interesting information I've been able to extract is this part :

```
at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:498) 
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.GroupValidationContextImpl.collectValidated(GroupValidationContextImpl.java:133) 
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ClassValidator.validateBeanNet(ClassValidator.java:421) 
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ClassValidator.validate(ClassValidator.java:141) 
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:136) 
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreUpdate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:102) 
at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.preUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:237) 
at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:86) 
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273) 
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265) 
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:185) 
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321) 
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51) 
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216) 
at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcess.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcess.java:155) 
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:543) 
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:216) 
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:571) 
at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.beforeTransactionCompletion(JDBCContext.java:250) 
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:138) 
at com.my_company.business.controller.GenericBusinessController.endOperation(GenericBusinessController.java:86) 
at com.my_company.business.controller.referentiel.FaqBusinessController.enregistrer(FaqBusinessController.java:104) 
at com.my_company.business.controller.referentiel.FaqBusinessController.enregistrer(FaqBusinessController.java:24) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) 
at com.ideo.sweetdev.core.service.remoting.ServerRemotingService.invokeMethod(ServerRemotingService.java:402) 
at com.ideo.sweetdev.core.service.remoting.ServerRemotingService.executeEvent(ServerRemotingService.java:255) 
at com.my_company.ejb.EjbFacade.execute(EjbFacade.java:41) 
at com.my_company.ejb.EJSRemote0SLEjbFacade_9c04bdc1.execute(EJSRemote0SLEjbFacade_9c04bdc1.java) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) 
at com.ibm.rmi.util.ProxyUtil$4.run(ProxyUtil.java:609) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:254) 
at com.ibm.rmi.util.ProxyUtil.invokeWithClassLoaders(ProxyUtil.java:606) 
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.invoke(ClientDelegate.java:1177) 
at $Proxy44.execute(Unknown Source) 
at com.my_company.ejb._EjbFacadeRemote_Stub.execute(_EjbFacadeRemote_Stub.java) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) 
at com.ideo.sweetdev.core.util.ReflectHelper.invokeMethod(ReflectHelper.java:485) 
at com.ideo.sweetdev.core.service.broker.ejbconnector.EJBConnector.invokeMethod(EJBConnector.java:206) 
at com.ideo.sweetdev.core.service.broker.ejbconnector.EJBConnector.execute(EJBConnector.java:110) 
at com.ideo.sweetdev.core.service.broker.Broker.executeService(Broker.java:369) 
at com.ideo.sweetdev.core.service.broker.Broker.execute(Broker.java:252) 
at com.ideo.sweetdev.core.service.remoting.RemotingService.invokeBusinessMethod(RemotingService.java:156) 
at com.ideo.sweetdev.core.service.remoting.RemotingInvocationHandler.invoke(RemotingInvocationHandler.java:67)
```

I can't figure out why there's a stackOverflowError when I add Envers and auditing to this simple object. This error occurs for every entity I try to save.
If you need more details, I'll answer as quick as I can.